# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\mysqli_connect.php on line 8

Tags: php, syntax-error

Hi I am trying to get a basic web page using code from http://www.larryullman.com/books/php-6-and-mysql-5-for-dynamic-web-sites-visual-quickpro-guide-3rd-edition/

I am getting this error when I click on the "View User's" link in this webpage. There is more code which I will post if necessary although. The line in question is bolded.

```
<?php - mysqli_connect.php

// This file contains the database access information. 
// This file also establishes a connection to MySQL 
// and selects the database.

// Set the database access information as constants:
**DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'username');**
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'sitename');

// Make the connection:
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_error() );

?>
```

Comment: Are those asterisks really in the code or were you attempting to bold the line using markdown? How about that `- mysqli_connect.php` bit? Please post the actual code.

Comment: `<?php - mysqli_connect.php` -- remove `- mysqli_connect.php`?

Comment: @Phil Brown: Editing your _comment_ to include what I said..? Isn't that a bit much? o_O

Comment: @stealthyninja Only saw yours after my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line, remove the `- mysqli_connect.php` part because that is not valid PHP. If you want to include it, change the first line to `<?php // mysqli_connect.php`.

EDIT: I corrected my post because my initial thought was completely wrong

Comment: IIRC PHP functions in the global namespace are case insensitive

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean `define('DB_USER', 'username');` ?

And I think that `- mysqli_connect.php` should be removed.